# How to get list of dates from Kendo Recurrence Rule?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

For example if recurrence rule like as below then how can i  get list of dates
 FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=2;BYDAY=-1TU;WKST=SU

Answer (score 0):

I found that [JS library](https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule) that gets all the ocurrences dates, get a slice...

[Here](http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/) you can see a web demo.

Example of use in code:

```
var rule = RRule.fromString(entry.RecurrentRule); // get RRule 

if (rule.between(date, addDays(date,+1), false, false) != "")
{ // check if overlap
    ids_elements.push(entry.ElementId);
}
```